# Get meta tags from url with DOM crawler

Tags: php, symfony, dom, meta-tags, domcrawler

I have installed `symfony/dom-crawler` in my project.
I am trying to get some of the meta tags from the URL of some random site to test.

```
$url = 'https://www.lala.rs/fun/this-news';

$crawler = new Crawler($url);

$data = $crawler->filterXpath("//meta[@name='description']")->extract(array('content'));
```

And it always returns `[]` as result.

I have tried with basic like meta description but maybe I do not understand it right.
I checked the [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) but could not find the right approach for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass HTML content to the `new Crawler($html)` and not a URL.

> Works fine on this page, using `viewport`, because of missing `description`.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

```
$url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66494027/get-meta-tags-from-url-with-dom-crawler';
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$crawler = new Crawler($html);

$data = $crawler->filterXpath("//meta[@name='viewport']")->extract(['content']);
```

Which gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0
)
```